# How does quorum blockchain achieve consensus in private transactions?

Tags: blockchain

I have visited many sites and read many blogs but still I am not getting how does quorum blockchain achieve consensus in private transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quorum Blockchain does not have consensus on private transactions at least until now.It has consensus on block level.It has pluggable consensus for public part of blockchain you may choose between RAFT , IBFT or Clique(POA). but these apply on blocks and not on private transactions. They have modified the EVM to not check for successful completion of private transactions.It is an open issue: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/62